# Internal Server Error while using PlatformIO extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions, platformio

PlatformIO was working fine. All of a sudden it started showing Internal Server Error when clicking PIO Home-->Open

Other features like:

Update All

Core CLI works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering `pio home` command
in the PlatformIO Core CLI revealed the problem.

It showed
`module 'anyio' has no attribute 'to_thread'` error.

I updated anyio to 3.5 and it sorted the problem.

**Conclusion:** This "all of a sudden" seems to be because of a switch from Python 3.10 to Python 3.8.3 which I had to do for another project at some point and 3.8.3 did not have the required anyio.

For anyone else bumping into this question with this same error trying

`pio home`

in the PlatformIO Core CLI may lead to a solution.